# How to make Local Date Time Zone to be equal (+8) to Server Time Zone (UTC) . Node js and AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, utc, gmt

I have a function that will calculate prices of data base on registered date. When I checked the results in my local and AWS server it had different result.
I have compared my date logs from my local server to AWS server and the results are different.

The result of the dates to be use in the query in local and AWS server:

Local:
Thu Feb 01 2018 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)  =====  Thu Mar 01 2018 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)

Server:
Fri Feb 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)  =====  Fri Mar 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)

Code:

```
date = new Date(); // set current date
from = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
to = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 1);
from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1); // set date + 1
from.setHours(from.getHours() - from.getUTCHours());
to.setDate(to.getDate() + 1); // set date + 1
to.setHours(to.getHours() - to.getUTCHours());
```

Result for from and to in local:

```
2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Result for from and to in server:

```
2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
2018-02-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

- Is this the cause of different results?
- How to fix this?

Comment: those times are exactly 24 hours apart - so,  yeah, something's amiss - though, what is a "date log"?

Comment: Thanks for the response @JaromandaX . The date log is the result of the dates that are going to be use in the filters when I test my code in my local and also try it also on AWS server.

Comment: sure, but why are they 24 hours apart? how are they created (incorrectly by the look of it)

Comment: My bad @JaromandaX . I already updated my question. I added the code on getting date for from and to to use in filtering data by date. The results are listed above.

Comment: `from.setHours(from.getHours() - from.getUTCHours());` why? what do you think this achieves? `new Date(2018,1,1)` no matter which timezone you are in should result in exactly the same result ... `2018-02-01T00:00:00Z` - so why are you fiddling with the hours?

Comment: In my result of `from` without setting the `from.setHours(from.getHours() - from.getUTCHours()) // setting the hours to zero` is `2018-01-01T16:00:00.000Z`. This is to get all the results from this month data.

Comment: hmm - dates are a nuisance !!!

Comment: nevermind ... new Date(2018,1,1) doesn't do what I said :p - as I said ... dates are a nuisance

Comment: Yeah.. I have so many testing in my local and the result is the above code. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: OK ... so which one is right? look into `from = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1))` - this from **will** always be `2018-02-01T00:00:00Z` - i.e. midnight UTC - regardless of local timezone - see the third note [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

Comment: @JaromandaX, It is ok now. The local and AWS server now have the same results in dates. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions. If you want to ask a new different question, please use the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 0):

So the question body has been changed and no longer makes sense, but the question in the title can be answered:

You can use the `Date.UTC` constructor

Comment: I've rolled back their edit. Such radical changes are unacceptable.